# C# method for element by element difference of an array (derivative approximation)?

Tags: c#

I normally use python but am learning C#, is there a preexisting class in C# for getting an element-by-element difference of an array to basically get a derivative, like numpy.diff in python?

Comment: Do you have meaningful sample data, have you tried something?

Comment: blinkenlight already basically did it...thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), `numpy.diff` does this:

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 0])
>>> np.diff(x)
array([ 1,  2,  3, -7])
```

If this is the effect that you want to see, use LINQ:

```
var np = new [] {1, 2, 4, 7, 0};
var res = np.Zip(np.Skip(1), (a,b)=>b-a).ToArray();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/CAHkcE)

Comment: var samplingBuffer = _samplingBuffer.GetAsArray();
var differences = new List<decimal>();
for (int i = 1; i < samplingBuffer.Length; i++)
{
    decimal difference = samplingBuffer[i] - samplingBuffer[i - 1];
    differences.Add(difference);
}