# How do I compute the second derivative of an one dimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, math

How do I compute the second derivative of an one dimensional array  in C#?
has anyone  done this before ?

Comment: Try to be more specific. Do you mean you have a single array of values, for example y = [1, 7, 17, 31, 49, 71, 97], and you want to assume a constant dx value, and therefore compute the approximate (i.e. mean) derivative and 2nd derivative?

Comment: First differences approximate the first derivative; second differences the second.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: at Joshua Huber Yes that is what I mean

Comment: lol see I was specific , because you knew what I was talking about

Comment: [like so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902728/c-sharp-method-for-element-by-element-difference-of-an-array-derivative-approxi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare an extension method that returns pairs of sequential numbers:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T Previous, T Next)> PreviousAndNext<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self)
{
    using (var iter = self.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iter.MoveNext())
            yield break;
        var previous = iter.Current;
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            var next = iter.Current;
            yield return (previous, next);
            previous = next;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the [discrete derivative](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Discrete_derivative), i.e. difference between sequential numbers you would do: `myArray.PreviousAndNext().Select((p, n) => n-p)`. If you want the second discrete derivative you would just repeat the function, i.e.

```
myArray.PreviousAndNext().Select((p, n) => n-p)
       .PreviousAndNext().Select((p, n) => n-p);
```

You could repeat this pattern however many times you want.